# Script to copy text in vim and paste to different window

Tags: vim, autohotkey, alt-tab, autokey

I've been trying to get a script working which would copy a line of text from vim, delete the line, then paste the line to another window. So far I've tried implementing the script with Autohotkey (on Windows 8) and Autokey (on a Ubuntu VM I run). Here's what I've put down:

On Autohotkey:

```
!^p::
SendRaw "*yydd
SendEvent !{tab}
SendPlay ^v
```

On Autokey (linked to Ctrl+Alt+p):

```
keyboard.send_keys("\"*yydd")
keyboard.send_keys("%{TAB}")
keyboard.send_keys("^v")
```

In both instances, the Vim commands (yank current line to system clipboard, delete current line) work properly, but the scripts fail to switch windows for the paste, and instead execute a Ctrl-v in vim.

Does anyone know what I would need to change in order to get the Alt-Tab functionality working?

Comment: I have zero experience with either autokey or autohotkey but, on vim's front, you could simply use `"*dd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending the raw <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys doesn't work, as application switching is a core Windows function. In AutoHotKey, there's the `AltTab` special command (look it up in the help), or better use the `WinActivate` command, as AutoHotKey seems to [still have issues with Alt-Tab on Windows 8](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/86218-how-can-i-emulate-alt-tab-function-on-win-8-using-ahk/).